# Why does my process counting script give false positives?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, scripting

I have the following bash script, that lists the current number of httpd processes, and if it is over 60, it should email me. This works 80% of the time but for some reason sometimes it emails me anyways when it is not over 60. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=`ps -ef|grep httpd| wc -l`
if [ "$lines" -gt "60" ]
then
        mailx -s "Over 60 httpd processes" me@me.com < /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: Please consider retitling this item so the responses can be more useful in search results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is a delay between checking and emailing. In that time, some `httpd` processes might finish, or start, or both. So, the number of processes can be different.
2. You are including the `grep` process in the processes (most of the time, it could happen that the `ps` finishes before `grep` starts).  An easy way to avoid that is to change your command to `ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd`.  This will make sure that `grep` doesn't match `grep [h]ttpd`.
3. On linux, you have `pgrep`, which might be better suited for your purposes.
4. `grep ... | wc -l` can usually be replaced with `grep -c ...`.
5. If you want to limit the number of httpd requests, I am sure you can set it in apache configuration files.

Comment: grep [h]ttpd is neat, didn’t know that …

Comment: Alok's 5th point is probably the most relevant thing here. Having to manually monitor the number of processed you have is not exactly "best practice" unless you're looking for a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You've probably thought of this, but ...

At time t0, there are 61.

At time t1, when you read the email, there are 58.

Try including the value of $lines in the email and you'll see.

Or try using /proc/*/cmdline, it might be more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

`grep httpd` finds all processes that include httpd in their name, including possibly `grep httpd` itself, and perhaps other ones.

Comment: You can do `grep [h]ttpd` to eliminate the `grep` from being included.

Answer (score 1):

"ps -ef|grep httpd" doesn't find just httpd processes, does it?  It finds processes whose full (-f) listing in ps includes the string "httpd".

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't solve your issue but you could simplify things by using `pgrep` instead.

Comment: Yes! This is easier and more reliable than grepping ps output.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way too, reducing the use of grep and wc to just one awk.

```
ps -eo args|awk '!/awk/&&/httpd/{++c}
END{
    if (c>60){
        cmd="mailx -s \047Over 60\047 root"
        cmd | getline
    }
}'
```